# Assign an array of values to an empty HTML tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, django, forms

I have some values in a table with the same tag name:

```
{% for groups in groupList %}
    <tr>
        <td id="checkboxes">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check_{{groups.GroupID}}">
        </td>
    <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However I want this data to be somewhere else so I can use it in a form for a POST request. Here is my form HTML:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="create"> Create Report for Selected Items </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="selected" value="" />
</form>
```

I've been trying to transfer the values from `check` into `selected` using JavaScript. Here's what I have so far:

```
function getChecked()
        {
                var checked = document.getElementsByName("check");
                var i = 0;
                for (a in checked)
                {
                        document.getElementsByName("selected")[i].value = a.value;
                        i = i + 1;
                }
        }
```

I've checked Google Chrome console and I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
at getChecked (1:75)
```

That highlights this line:

```
document.getElementsByName("selected")[i].value = a.value;
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Sounds like you have more `check`s than `selected`s (but also, you probably want to access the `a` property of `checked`, not `checked.value` - consider using more precise variable names or a type checker)

Comment: Try `for (a of checked)`. Using the `of` keyword lets you loop through arrays or nodelists, rather than `in` which is for objects.

Comment: This does not seems to have anything to do with Django. Please post a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor with plain HTML and script only.

Comment: @mplungjan It is a Django template as seen by the for tags. I included it in this question as there may be potential solutions using view/template.

Comment: _I want to transfer the values from check into selected using JavaScript._

Comment: I should probably change my wording there then. Will edit the question. What I mean to say is "I've been trying to" in place of "I want to". I'm open to solutions using other methods

Comment: You're trying to access to the nth `selected` input, where n is the amount of `check` inputs, but you have only one `selected` input.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to send the `id` of selected **checkboxes** as an array of **hidden inputs**.

For example, if you have selected the checkbox **check_1**, **check_2**, and **check_3**, you can build the form as

```html
<form ...>
  <input type="hidden" name="selected[]" value="checkbox_1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="selected[]" value="checkbox_2"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="selected[]" value="checkbox_3"/>

  <input type="submit" ... />
</form>
```

In your server you will receive `selected` as an array

```js
request.POST['selected'] // ["checkbox_1", "checkbox_2", "checkbox_3"]
```

To build all the hidden inputs when the user click the submit button you can do:

- 1. give an **id** to your form to access it thought javascript

```html
<form id="my-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit" name="create"> Create Report for Selected Items 
  </button>
</form>
```

- 2. add the following script

```js
<script>
var form = document.getElementById('my-form');  // get the form

// when the user submit the form execute the following function
form.onsubmit = function() {
  document.getElementsByName('check')  // get all checkboxes
    .forEach(function(checkInput) {
      // if the checkbox is selected
      if (checkInput.checked) {
        // create a new hidden input and add into the form
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'selected[]');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', checkInput.getAttribute('id'));
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
      }
    });
  return true;  // return true to continue the submit execution
};
</script>
```

Comment: This project sets no limits on how many checkboxes can be in the table though. I have no way of writing out enough hidden input fields to cover every possibility surely?

Comment: @Cm0295 Of course, you don't need to create the hidden inputs by hand. The code I purpose you create the hidden inputs dynamically when you click the submit button.